# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pycountry' even though it is installed

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, modulenotfounderror

I got this error from python `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pycountry'`.

I imported the module using `pip` and `pip3` and I've also tried running my code in terminal using python, python3, and IDLE.

Why doesn't python recognize the `module`? I'm receiving the same error about `plotly` and `pandas` as well.

```
import pycountry
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

URL_DATASET = r'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasets/covid-19/master/data/countries-aggregated.csv     '
df1 = pd.read_csv(URL_DATASET)

list_countries = df1['Country'].unique().tolist()
d_country_code = {}
```

Comment: which python version are u using?

Comment: what is your script name? have you installed the dependencies? which version of python you are working on?

Comment: the environment you are running in may don't have these dependencies installed. Please check you are running in the right environment

Comment: "pip list" or "pip3 list" to see what is installed - or you could do "python[3] -m pip list"Is pycountry in there?

Comment: I've tried using terminal and IDLE. How can I install any missing dependencies?

Comment: @sand are you on a given environment?

Answer (score 0):

Open your command window and then use this code there.

> pip install pycountry

This will install the whole package in your system, so whenever you import the module, it will not show an error.

This worked for me, I was facing the same issue while using it in Jupyter Notebook.
If you want more information please visit [this page](https://pypi.org/project/pycountry/).

Answer (score 0):

If you have Anaconda, try:

```sh
conda install -c conda-forge pycountry
```